# Is that possible to get same value in solidity as python?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, remix

for example in python
a = 1014081517999420713613407064382286109869722468164044763562956108953
b = 75112238216995383638638265438238982594702004617177809015442110861252064955580

when i try to multiply i.e a*b iam getting 76169932551424780542197024607564545402453865908431390460596505235905835211022255056422196565602043527214611665408223471810048772669727585307740

but when i try to do same calculation in solidty iam getting different value
uint256 aa = 1014081517999420713613407064382286109869722468164044763562956108953
uint256 bb = 75112238216995383638638265438238982594702004617177809015442110861252064955580

result is 80926084372948586918761472606712001111506590507024938269237453828706263600220

is there any method that i can get the same value in soldity as iam getting in python

pl let me know